# How to strip variable out of knot parameter dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a dataframe of statsmodels coefficients. I need to strip the variable name out to join to another table.

Below is code for what I currently have and what I want.

The general statement is the same `bs(np.clip(#variable name#, 0, np.inf), degree = 1, knots = [insert knots][number]`

Variables can change so I was hoping for something robust enough to pull whatever variable out of the general statement.

```
import pandas as pd
#current

dict = {'index': ['bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

df1

# Solution

dict2 = {'index': ['bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'],
       'desired': ['vehicle_age_model','vehicle_age_model','vehicle_age_model'
                   , 'driver_age_model', 'driver_age_model', 'length_ft_model','length_ft_model' ]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)

df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution is :

```
 import re
 def convert(x):
     pattern= re.compile(r"(bs\(np.clip\()(\w*)\,")
     match = pattern.search(x)
     if match:
        return match.group(2)
     return x
 df1['index'].apply(convert)
```

Comment: yep, that's better!  Not sure what all of that means but thank you!  Is it possible to pull the numbers after knots inside the [] and place them in their own column?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard.  Trial and error yielded this ugly result.

`df['index'].str.replace('bs\(np.clip\(', '').str.replace(', 0, np.inf\), degree=1, knots\=\[', '').str.replace('[,\.\)\[\]!?0-9]', '').str.strip()`